# How to delete every second line from a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

File:

```
Data inserted into table. Total count 13
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 45
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 14
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 90
No error occurred
```

Expected output file:

```
Data inserted into table. Total count 13
Data inserted into table. Total count 45
Data inserted into table. Total count 14
Data inserted into table. Total count 90
```

I want the output to look this way: every second line will be deleted but there will be no gap between lines.

Comment: Do you want to delete every second line or all lines that contains *"No error occurred"*? What if two consecutive lines had *"No error occurred"*?

Comment: @user1598390 I think... in that case `grep -v "No error occurred" file` this command should work... what @paul has answered. In the output file, there will be no lines containing "No error occurred" this part.

Comment: Then the title of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e n\;d <file
```

With POSIX `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR%2' <file
```

If you have older `awk` (like `oawk`), you need:

```
oawk 'NR%2 == 1' <file
```

With `ex`:

```
$ ex file <<\EX
:g/$/+d
:wq!
EX
```

will edit the file in-place.

- `g` mark a global command
- `/$/` match every lines
- `+d` delete the next line
- `wq!` save all changes

This approach share the same ideal with `sed` approach, delete every next line of current line start from line 1.

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 2' <file
```

and `raku`:

```
raku -ne '.say if $*IN.ins % 2' <file
raku -ne '.say if ++$ % 2' <file
```

**Edit**

Raku `IO::Handle.ins` was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/77fc44d9c0fb6025be0ed1b2506cde996f6c8db6).

Comment: Yes... its working ... :)  ... first one is working.... i have also tried the second one.. its telling `awk : syntax error line1 awk: bailing out near line 1'

Comment: sed -e n\;d <file ~ Yes its working @cuonglm...

Comment: @Nainita: my `awk` required POSIX awk, updated with solution for older one.

Comment: Yes this command oawk 'NR%2 == 1' is working... :)

Comment: Some comments on how these lines work would be appreciated.

Comment: @MarkH: What solution you need explanation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `sed` command used here. The others I can figure out, but future readers would benefit from having these commands explained in the answer instead of just being presented with a mysterious sequence of characters (especially the `ex` command, and I'm speaking as a `vim` user).

Comment: @MarkH: The `sed` command is very simple, with two `sed` command only. If you read the `sed` document, I'm sure you will get it. Going to update the `ex` part.

Comment: I'm guessing that you used `n\;d` instead of `'n;d'` to save a precious character but that logic goes out of the window when you're unnecessarily using the `-e` switch and a file redirection `<`!

Comment: @TomFenech: `<file` protect you from files which start with dash `-`. `-e` is just my habit, you can see it in all my `sed` answer.

Comment: @cuonglm Can you please explain the `n\;d` part of `sed -e n\;d <file' ?

Comment: @Geek: It's just a shorter version of `sed -e 'n;d'`, save you one character.

Comment: @ cuonglm I know that `-n` command suppress the normal output. `d` would delete the match. But what role is `n` playing here especially context of deleting every second line?

Comment: @cuonglm is it like reading the every second second line into the pattern space followed by deleting the same?

Comment: @Geek: `n` command write pattern space to standard output if `-n` was used, then replace pattern space with next line. Here's every odd line will be printed by `n`, even line then read into pattern space but delete immediately by `d` command`.

Comment: @cuonglm Hi your second perl6 (a.k.a. Raku) answer works fine, but the first one gives me an error, saying: `No such method 'ins' for invocant of type 'IO::Handle'
  in block <unit> at -e line 1` .  Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: @jubilatious1 `.ins` was removed in commit https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/77fc44d9c0fb6025be0ed1b2506cde996f6c8db6

Answer (score 63):

Solving this by deleting every second line can be error prone (for example, when process sometimes generates two meaningful lines instead one).
May be it is better to filter out the garbage:

```
grep -v "No error occurred" file
```

It can run as filter, you can add more garbage patterns here and improve the result.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that sometimes the second line is important!

Answer (score 13):

Ассоrding to the question, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '0~2d' file
```

will delete every second line but I'd like to offer filter lines by it content:

```
sed '/Data/! d' file
```

or with same result

```
sed '/No error/d' file
```

Comment: sed '/No error/d' file ~ gives the desired output @Costas

Comment: Note that  the last two are convoluted ways to write `grep Data` and `grep -v 'No error'`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way using `sed`:

```
sed -n 'p;n' filename
```

Another way with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '1~2p' filename
```

Output from above commands:

```
Data inserted into table. Total count 13
Data inserted into table. Total count 45
Data inserted into table. Total count 14
Data inserted into table. Total count 90
```

Comment: What do you mean when saying `shortest way using sed`?

Comment: What is the reason in `g` command? `sed -n 'p;n'` is enough.

Comment: @cuonglm: I mean to say simple way of doing. By the way removed that word. :)

Comment: @Costas: Thanks! Just checked, its working without `g`. removed g from command. :)

Answer (score 5):

Another answer, you could use vi/vim!

> qdjddq

And then if your file was 500 lines (for example) type

> 250@d

And then to write and exit type

> :x

Or if something goes wrong and you don't want to save:

> :q!

Explanation:

```
q      #Start Recording
 d     #Put the recording into register 'd'
  j    #Move the cursor down
   dd  #Delete the line
     q #Stop recording
```

```
250    #Number of repeats
   @d  #Playback the recording in register 'd'.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR % 2 != 0' file
```

or you can print only lines containing `Data inserted`:

```
awk '$0 ~ /Data inserted/' file
```

Comment: I have tried both of you answers and both are working... :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's quite a different way of doing it:

```
< file paste - - | cut -f1
```

This assumes that the odd-numbered lines do not contain tabs.  If they do, then you'll need to pick another separator character, e.g. `:` here:

```
< file paste -d: - - | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: I had this in mind when I first saw the question... It'd be interesting to run a speed test against `sed` with a huge file (e.g. 20 mil lines). Anyways, +1 but really, to avoid headaches, pick a delimiter that's unlikely to occur in a text file, like `$'\002'`...

Comment: @don_crissti yes use of a non-printing character for the separator is a good idea.  And yes, this is measurably faster than the sed solution.  I created a test file with `seq 100000000 > 100mil.txt`.  The `paste|cut` solution finished in about 7.5 seconds, vs nearly 12 for the `sed` solution.  Seems to be repeatable.  `grep` is fastest though. Ubuntu 14.04 with standard GNU tools.

Comment: Yep, `paste` + `cut` are heavily optimized for their job so unsurprisingly their combination is pretty damn fast...

Answer (score 1):

Another option (shorter)

```
sed 'n; d' file
```

Comment: It's longer than mine `sed n\;d`, adding `-e` is only my habit.

Answer (score 0):

It also solves the problem, though it is a bit slower:

```
vim -c "%normal jdd" -c "wq" file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -pe 'get;' file
```

Sample Input:

```
Data inserted into table. Total count 13
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 45
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 14
No error occurred
Data inserted into table. Total count 90
No error occurred
```

Sample Output:

```
Data inserted into table. Total count 13
Data inserted into table. Total count 45
Data inserted into table. Total count 14
Data inserted into table. Total count 90
```

There's already an answer using Raku from @cuonglm, which uses the one-liner `raku -ne '.say if ++$ % 2'`. Above is a different approach using Raku's `get` routine instead. In combination with the `-pe` (autoprinting) command-line flags, Raku's `get` routine advances the readline-cursor by a line, which (because `-pe` prints return values not the `$_` topic variable) results in that line `get`-ting discarded. Only the first, third, fifth, etc. lines are printed.

Need to print the second, fourth, sixth lines, etc. instead of above? Just use Raku's `-ne` command-line flags. Here Raku's `get` routine advances the readline-cursor by a line, and **then** `.put` is called, giving the following output:

```
~$ raku -ne 'get.put;'  file
No error occurred
No error occurred
No error occurred
No error occurred
```

https://raku.org